# How to hide default list view dashlet based on user roles in sugar crm?

Tags: dashboard, sugarcrm, suitecrm, dashlet

How to hide default list view dashlet based on user roles in sugar crm ? OR
How can i restrist user from adding list view dashlet based on user role ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have SuiteCRM 7.10.7, might not apply to newer, and this change is not upgrade safe.

You could modify getDashlets function in DashletDialog
 `include/MySugar/DashletsDialog/DashletsDialog.php`

It has the loop which loads in all dashlets to choose. You could put some limitations in there (get `$current_user` groups, check if they're ok and if particular dashlet should(n't) be allowed for them).